# Kendo Grid - Create Transport, ID not set

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

See this question with no response: [Kendo Grid does not update the grid with newly created id after creation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19171339/302994)

When creating a new link, my method is hit, and I return the full item with the ID set:

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Create(string LINK_TEXT, string HREF, string CATEGORY)
        {
            var link = new LinkDTO {LINK_TEXT = LINK_TEXT, HREF = HREF, CATEGORY = CATEGORY};
            var insertedLink = LinkService.Create(link);
            return Json(new[] {insertedLink}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

In the client, the response is:

```
{"ID":86,"LINK_TEXT":"Test2","HREF":"http://www.google.com","CATEGORY":"Category1"}
```

I've also tried only returning the ID:

{"ID":86}

Upon inspection of the kendo data:

```
CATEGORY: "Category1"
HREF: "http://www.google.com"
ID: 0
LINK_TEXT: "Test2"
_events: Object
dirty: false
id: 0
parent: function (){return r}
uid: "4739cc3d-a270-44dd-9c63-e9d378433d98"
```

The ID is 0. When I try to edit this link it thinks it is new, so it calls create again, thus duplicating the link.

Here is my grid definition:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#link-results").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    create: {
                        url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Link")',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: 'POST'
                    },
                    read: {
                        url: '@Url.Action("Read", "Link")',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: 'GET',
                        data: {
                            CATEGORY: '@Model.CategoryName'
                        }
                    },
                    update: {
                        url: '@Url.Action("Update", "Link")',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {
                            CATEGORY: '@Model.CategoryName'
                        }
                    },
                    destroy: {
                        url: '@Url.Action("Delete", "Link")',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: 'POST'
                    }
                },
                pageSize: 10,
                schema: {
                    data: "Links",
                    total: "ResultCount",
                    model: {
                        id: "ID",
                        fields: {
                            ID: {type: "number"},
                            LINK_TEXT: { type: "string", required: true },
                            HREF: { type: "string", defaultValue: "", validation: { required: true } },
                            CATEGORY: { type: "string", defaultValue: '@Model.CategoryName', editable: false }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            pageable: true,
            toolbar: ["create"],
            columns: [
                { field: "ID", hidden: true },
                { field: "LINK_TEXT", title: "Name", width: "40px"/*, template: "<a href='#=HREF#'>#=LINK_TEXT#</a>"*/ },
                { field: "HREF", title: "Link", width: "100px",filterable: false/*, template: "<a href='#=HREF#'>#=HREF#</a>"*/ },
                { field: "CATEGORY", title: "Category", width: "50px", filterable: false},
                {
                    command: [
                        { name: "edit", text: "" },
                        { name: "destroy", text: "" }
                    ],
                    title: "&nbsp;",
                    width: "70px"
                }
            ],
            editable: "inline",
            filterable: true,
            sortable: "true"
        });
```

I added the `ID: {type: "number"},` part in an attempt to get this to work, I realize I should not need this in my fields definition since it is defined with `id: "ID"`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was, here is the text from another answer I provided regarding the same issue (see [Kendo Grid does not update the grid with newly created id after creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19171339/kendo-grid-does-not-update-the-grid-with-newly-created-id-after-creation/19931949#19931949)):

I've had the same problem and think I may have found the answer. If in the schema you define the object that holds the results, you must return the result of the created link in that same object. Example:

```
schema: {
         data: "data",        
         total: "total",  .... 
 }
```

Example MVC method:

```
public JsonResult CreateNewRow(RowModel rowModel)
{
    // rowModel.id will be defaulted to 0

    // save row to server and get new id back
    var newId = SaveRowToServer(rowModel);

    // set new id to model
    rowModel.id = newId;

    return Json(new {data= new[] {rowModel}});
}
```